# HTML CSS background cut off at the top

Tags: html, css

```css
.footer-bar {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.footer-bar a {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: var(--smlink);
  font-size: 20px;
}
.youtube {
  background: #FF0000;
  color: var(--smlink);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-socialbar">
    <div class="footer-bar">
        <a href="#" class="sm youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="sm facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a> 
        <a href="#" class="sm twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="sm spotify"><i class="fa fa-spotify fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wonder how I can make these buttons appear right so that the color appears around the whole link.
That's how they appear on the screen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qyeK.png
I want them not to like where cut off at the top, how can I achieve this?

The color of the links in CSS named .youtube

Posted only one color because the rest is exactly the same.

If anybody can help it would be great...
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're using the translation for so I took that out from the snippet below to address the issue. The anchor tags aren't displayed as block elements for you. If you put them inside a flexbox and give them an explicit size, they will work. The snippet works, but it doesn't have font-awesome, so you'll have to use your imagination with the result of it.

```css
.footer-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.footer-bar a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: var(--smlink);
    background: #a33;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.footer-bar a.youtube {
    background: #a33;
}

.footer-bar a.facebook {
    background: #00f;
}

.footer-bar a.twitter {
    background: #ff0;
}

.footer-bar a.spotify {
    background: #00703c;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-socialbar">
    <div class="footer-bar">
        <a href="#" class="sm youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="sm facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="sm twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="sm spotify"><i class="fa fa-spotify fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```